# Filling page when using `patchwork` and `ggplot2` with rmarkdown pdfs

Tags: ggplot2, r-markdown, raster, terra, patchwork

I'm trying to output a pdf showing 3 maps arranged using the `patchwork` library. I want the map combination to take up the full page width (in my case, 6.5 inches) so each individual map is as large as possible. When I plot without `patchwork`, the maps take up the entire space, as desired. When I plot with `patchwork`, I'm getting large areas of white space after arranging (see image). I've tried various hacks around plot margins but nothing works.

Here's a reproducible example, knitting to pdf. I used the `dismo` library to get an example raster file.

````
---
title: "Testing"
author: "Erica Newton"
date: "2023-06-23"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, echo = F, messages = F, warning = F, include = F}
library(ggspatial)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(sf)
library(terra)
library(raster)
library(tidyterra)
library(dismo)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))
b2 <- rast(system.file("ex/bio16.grd", package = "dismo"))
```


```{r, echo = F, fig.height = 7, fig.width = 6.5}
# respects my width and height arguments
a <- ggplot(nc) + 
  geom_sf() +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme_void() 

b <- ggplot(nc) + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  geom_sf(fill = "pink") +
  theme_void() 

(a + a) / b
```

```{r, echo = F, fig.height = 7, fig.width = 6.5}
c <- ggplot() + 
  geom_spatraster(data = b2) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "null"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "lightblue"))

c
```

```{r, echo = F, fig.height = 7, fig.width = 6.5}
# does not respect width and height argument
(a + b) / c + plot_annotation(theme = theme(plot.margin = margin()))
```
````

Here's what the output looks like.

**I'd also like to remove the white space between the top two images and the bottom image on the third page.**

[image: 3 map combo]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `plot_layout` function with `widths` argument like this:

````
```{r, echo = F, fig.height = 7, fig.width = 6.5}
(a + b) / c + plot_layout(heights = c(0.2,-1))
```
````

Output:

[image]

Comment: This does solve my problem, but I can't find a reference to what a negative number means. I've been looking here: https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/layout.html - any idea where to find more info?